# Compiler/Linking Error: Freedup

Tags: c, linker, compiler-errors, inline-functions

I've been trying to compile a program for hardlinking duplicate files called freedup. I did try to email the author/maintainer of the program, but it's been a long time and I haven't heard anything back from him.

I'm trying to compile the program from a cygwin environment using the latest stable versions of gcc (3.4.4-999) and make (3.81-2). I've tried deleting all the object files and running make, but I always get the following error:

> freedup.o: In function 'main':
>   /home/[user]/freedup-1.5/freedup.c:1791: undefined reference to '_hashed'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make: * * * [freedup] Error 1

I did take a look at the source code and saw that the "hashed" function is an inline function (which I didn't think had to be declared outside of the source file... but that's just what I gathered from some preliminary googling).

If anyone would be kind enough to try compiling this program in a windows environment and has any luck, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks

The direct link for the source files is: http://freedup.org/freedup-1.5-3-src.tgz

Comment: don't know about the compilation, but I've used a perl script for the actual task (hardlinking duplicates): http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ANDK/Perl-Repository-APC-2.002/eg/trimtrees.pl - maybe that works under Cygwin, too?

Comment: The source you linked to built fine for me using cygwin and gcc 3.4.4

Comment: Try removing the `inline` ... and hope the compiler inlines it anyway :)

Comment: @karoberts What windows and cygwin version were you using?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not impressed by code that uses '`#include <linux/stat.h>`' instead of '`#include <sys/stat.h>`'.  I'm also unimpressed by code where the version.h file contains:

```
-e #define VERSION "1.5-3"
```

(That file is generated by a command - '`echo -e '#define...' > version.h`'.  Ugh!)

If you change the function from:

```
inline int hashed(const char*s)
{
    int returnval=atoi(s);

    if(returnval>2) returnval=2;
    if(returnval<0) returnval=0;
    return returnval;
}
```

to:

```
static
inline int hashed(const char*s)
{
    int returnval=atoi(s);

    if(returnval>2) returnval=2;
    if(returnval<0) returnval=0;
    return returnval;
}
```

(and fix the other problems alluded to above), then it compiles on MacOS X 10.6.2 with GCC 
"i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646) (dot 1)".

The test code fails at random points since it assumes the touch in /bin/touch (it is /usr/bin/touch on MacOS X).  There are also many warnings about 'type qualifiers ignored on function return type' because 'auto.h' defines 4 functions as returning 'const int' (for various guises of 'int'), and also in function pointers in a structure in the same header.

I guess this comes down to insufficient experience on the part of the authors - or insufficient platforms tested.  The version.h command does not need to use a tab (I believe the '`-e`' is to expand the '`\t`' notation in the command line - the Makefile should be fixed to omit the '`-e`' and replace the '`\t`' with a simple blank.

The behaviour of '`inline`' in standard C99 is interesting:

### 6.7.4 Function specifiers

#### Syntax

> function-specifier:

```
    inline
```

#### Constraints

> Function specifiers shall be used only in the declaration of an identifier for a function.
>
> An inline definition of a function with external linkage shall not contain a definition of a
>   modifiable object with static storage duration, and shall not contain a reference to an
>   identifier with internal linkage.
>
> In a hosted environment, the inline function specifier shall not appear in a declaration
>   of main.

#### Semantics

> A function declared with an inline function specifier is an inline function. The
>   function specifier may appear more than once; the behavior is the same as if it appeared
>   only once. Making a function an inline function suggests that calls to the function be as
>   fast as possible.<sup>118)</sup> The extent to which such suggestions are effective is
>   implementation-defined.<sup>119)</sup>
>
> Any function with internal linkage can be an inline function. For a function with external
>   linkage, the following restrictions apply: If a function is declared with an inline
>   function specifier, then it shall also be defined in the same translation unit. If all of the
>   file scope declarations for a function in a translation unit include the inline function
>   specifier without extern, then the definition in that translation unit is an inline
>   definition. An inline definition does not provide an external definition for the function,
>   and does not forbid an external definition in another translation unit. An inline definition
>   provides an alternative to an external definition, which a translator may use to implement
>   any call to the function in the same translation unit. It is unspecified whether a call to the
>   function uses the inline definition or the external definition.<sup>120)</sup>
>
> <sup>118)</sup> By using, for example, an alternative to the usual function call mechanism, such as ‘‘inline
>   substitution’’. Inline substitution is not textual substitution, nor does it create a new function.
>   Therefore, for example, the expansion of a macro used within the body of the function uses the
>   definition it had at the point the function body appears, and not where the function is called; and
>   identifiers refer to the declarations in scope where the body occurs. Likewise, the function has a
>   single address, regardless of the number of inline definitions that occur in addition to the external
>   definition.
>
> <sup>119)</sup> For example, an implementation might never perform inline substitution, or might only perform inline
>   substitutions to calls in the scope of an inline declaration.
>
> <sup>120)</sup> Since an inline definition is distinct from the corresponding external definition and from any other
>   corresponding inline definitions in other translation units, all corresponding objects with static storage
>   duration are also distinct in each of the definitions.

Comment: correct on all counts.  Inline functions are tricky.  If you compile without optimization, and the compiler doesn't inline your function, then you will get a link error if you don't put extern inline foo(); in one .c file to force a non-inline definition to be emitted there.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan Leffler provides the answer for freedup 1.5.3: add 'static' or remove 'inline' on the hashed function.  (You should probably accept that answer.)

freedup 1.6-* doesn't compile on Cygwin at all:

```
socket.c:20:26: fatal error: net/ethernet.h: No such file or directory
```

This file doesn't exist in Cygwin.